# How to encode a file NSURL to point to a file with a '/' in the name

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm reading a file with a slash in its name. I can verify that it exists in the path where I'm looking for it, but creating an `NSData` from it fails. I've tried replacing the `/` with a `%2F` in the string I'm using to build the URL, but it didn't make a difference.

This is the code that constructs the URL:

```
let fileID = "This/That"
let filename = "\(fileID).json"

let bundleDirURL = myBundle.URLForResource("dirname", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "MyFiles")
let fileURL = bundleDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Subpath").URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
```

The list line is giving me a null data, even though the file exists in the correct path. I know it's the `/` that's tripping it up. How can I fix this? I need to keep the `/` in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is not actually a legal character in Darwin (OS X or iOS) file names. The UI just makes it *look* like it is in some cases. OS X exchanges `:` for `/`. So the actual name of your file is `This:That`. Depending on what tool you're using it will be rendered as either `This:That` or `This/That`. This is an old holdover from Mac OS 9. In Mac OS 9 and earlier, `:` is illegal, but `/` is legal. In Darwin (via OS X), the opposite is true.

You really, really want to avoid this situation if you can, and just not have `/` or `:` in your filenames (`-` and `_` are generally safer, and `.` is often fine). But if you must, then you're going to have to swap it for `:` in your string.